# python in vscode - can't get multiprocessing to work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-multiprocessing

I'm not new to Python, but pretty new to working with multiprocessing in Python. I prefer working in vscode, but it's acting very weird when I try to run a simple multiprocessing example.

I'm running Python 3.7.2 and VSCode version 1.43.0 on Windows.

Here's my files.  First the caller:

```
## multi_runner.py

import multiprocessing
import multi_worker
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting the jobs.')
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=multi_worker.worker
        )
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    while any(job.is_alive() for job in jobs):
        print('sleeping')
        time.sleep(1)
    print('All done.')
```

And the worker:

```
## multi_worker.py

import multiprocessing
import sys

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print(f'Worker')
    return
```

When I run this at the command line, everything works the way you'd expect:

```
(venv) C:\multiexample>python multi_runner.py
Starting the jobs.
sleeping
Worker
Worker
Worker
Worker
Worker
All done.
```

But when I run it from within the VSCode debugger, it seems like it never yields to the workers, and I have to kill it to end it:

```
(venv) PS C:\multiexample>  ${env:PTVSD_LAUNCHER_PORT}='52842'; & 'c:\multiexample\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\myuser\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\new_ptvsd\wheels\ptvsd\launcher' 'c:\multiexample\multi_runner.py'
    Starting the jobs.
    sleeping
    sleeping
    sleeping
    sleeping
    sleeping
    sleeping
    sleeping
    sleeping
    sleeping
    <... forever ...>
```

Here's the default launch.json file I'm using:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to make this work in VSCode?

Comment: VS Code is good for many things.. for some specific tasks go with specialized editors like Pycharm.

Comment: Please try the latest debugger as outlined at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/2104 and see if that resolves the issue.